# swift nearby api doesn't find beacons

Tags: ios, swift, beacon, google-nearby

I want to use my swift ios app to scan for beacons using google nearby api (not iBeacon api)

I saw Google developer [doc](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/ios/get-started), and I took the git sample from the same site.

Here is my [code](https://gist.github.com/elad2109/744d633e00630c171858)

I have installed the app on a real ios device for the first time

but the `found` and `lost` handlers are never called.

I doubled checked the bundle id, the public ios API key (same google console project of the beacon attachment)

but it still doesn't work near a working and registered beacon.

I also have an android app which succeeds in scanning the same beacon.

What else can I check?

I'm missing the `"Strategy"` piece of code in my swift code.

How can I add this? Why is this missing in the github example?

```
GNSStrategy *beaconStrategy = [GNSStrategy
    strategyWithParamsBlock:^(GNSStrategyParams *params) {
      params.includeBLEBeacons = YES;
    }];
    GNSSubscriptionParams *beaconParams = [GNSSubscriptionParams
        paramsWithMessageNamespace:@"com.mycompany.mybeaconservice"
                              type:@"mybeacontype"
                          strategy:beaconStrategy];
    _beaconSubscription = [_messageManager subscriptionWithParams:beaconParams
                                              messageFoundHandler:myMessageFoundHandler
                                               messageLostHandler:myMessageLostHandler];
```

in my code:

```
func startScanning() {
    if let messageMgr = self.messageMgr {

        // Subscribe to messages from nearby devices and display them in the message view.
        subscription = messageMgr.subscriptionWithMessageFoundHandler({[unowned self] (message: GNSMessage!) -> Void in

            self.mainViewController.location_text.text = (String(data: message.content, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding))
            self.mainViewController.startRefreshTimer()
            },

            messageLostHandler: {[unowned self](message: GNSMessage!) -> Void in

                if (self.mainViewController.userState.enrollState == EnrollState.confirmPosition)
                {
                    self.mainViewController.stopRefreshTimer()
                    self.mainViewController.enrollButtonManager.setSearchingForBeaconsBtn()
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the GNSStrategy to your subscription, which lets you enable beacon scanning.  Try this:

```
let params: GNSSubscriptionParams = GNSSubscriptionParams.init(strategy:
    GNSStrategy.init(paramsBlock: { (params: GNSStrategyParams!) -> Void in
      params.includeBLEBeacons = true;
    }))
subscription = messageMgr.subscriptionWithParams(params,
    messageFoundHandler:{[unowned self] (message: GNSMessage!) -> Void in
      self.mainViewController.location_text.text = (String(data: message.content, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding))
      self.mainViewController.startRefreshTimer()
    },
    messageLostHandler: {[unowned self](message: GNSMessage!) -> Void in
      if (self.mainViewController.userState.enrollState == EnrollState.confirmPosition) {
        self.mainViewController.stopRefreshTimer()
        self.mainViewController.enrollButtonManager.setSearchingForBeaconsBtn()
      }
    })
```

Beacon scanning is off by default because iOS presents the user with the location permission dialog when beacon scanning is first turned on, and this is unacceptable for apps that use the Nearby library but don't scan for beacons.

Thanks for the feedback about the github example not showing how to scan for beacons.  I'll see about adding it.